# I get the error on Execution time

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, gmail-api

Error message
              `  Error:Execution failed for task 
        ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class`

build.gradle(Module.app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jd.travelsdemo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9', 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
   }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:2.0'
//gmail api dependencies
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev44-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'

}

compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   }
```

Comment: One of your 3rd party libraries is using a different version of a library you have referenced. It should be warning you in android studio that there is a mismatch. Look for one of your dependancies, being highlighed in orange/beige colour

Comment: post output from `gradlew app:dependencies`

Comment: it is to large output

Comment: compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4' it's use library compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' @Doomsknight

Comment: Try swapping your dependencies to `23.3.0` and then building, instead of `25.3.1`

Comment: still get same error @Doomsknight

Comment: @JigishDalal you should post as minimum part for `releaseCompileClasspath`

Answer (score 1):

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev67-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'

}
```

added exclude group as above.

Answer (score 0):

try this exclude the duplicated file by using below code

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
        }
```